# How do I connect to Secondary when Primary is offline

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 servers in a test lab, node1 & node2. I'm at the command prompt on node1.
I've run rs.stepDown() on node1, leaving just a SECONDARY running on node2.

I'm running the command : -

```
# mongosh "mongodb://node1:27017,node2:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=primaryPreferred"
```

Node1 is offline, but it's taking 60 seconds to connect to the secondary.
Should I be setting up something on the F5 to detect when host/ports are inaccessible ?

Comment: F5 won't help. Mongo has it's own primary election mechanism. The client is quite thick and is aware of the cluster topology. Read more here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-members/. 2 nodes repset is a tricky set up and is not recommended as it complicates re-election.  3 nodes repset usually come up with new primary in about 10-15 seconds, controlled by settings.electionTimeoutMillis config.

Comment: Thanks@AlexBlex. I'm new to Mongo, and aware of the 2 node problem. When I have 3 nodes, I'll want some users to connect to their Secondary only, unless it's offline in which case they'll connect to a remote sight. I can't see how to set that up, without a long delay.

Comment: "I'll want some users to connect to their Secondary only," - why?  There is a readpreference to read from secondary, but you cannot write to secondary and expect data to be synchronised.  What problem are you trying to solve the "remote site" thing sounds suspicious.

Comment: Because it'll be in a region local to that user, for low latency, read-only. Don't care so much about sync speed, but do care about read speed.

Comment: Replication is intended for redundancy, you are trying to re-purpose it for edge caching. Although it's not impossible, you should expect a lot of bumps on the road. It's like repurposing a razor-sharp axe for shaving - it will do the job to some degree but you need to understand risks.  If you are sure you want to follow this rabbit hole - connect to the secondary directly.

Comment: Then `readPreference=nearest` might be an option.